# htmlspecialchars is dropping characters

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to use `htmlspecialchars` but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using OSX 10.9.1 and PHP 5.4.17. I write:

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
echo htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_XHTML, 'UTF-8');
```

and get:

```
string '&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;' (length=45)
<a href='test'>Test</a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? All seems to be right.

Comment: Let me guess, you're viewing the rendered HTML and not the actual source. Also, `var_dump` will encode entities in an HTML context, in essence, double-encoding your string for output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works, but you expect something else.

The output is interpreted by your browser as HTML. You can get the plain output by setting the content type to plain or using a command line.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

var_dump(htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
echo htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_XHTML, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: ...or by clicking "View Source" in the browser

Comment: @IMSoP you shouldn't always trust your browser's "view source". Firefox modified the source in some cases some time ago, I don't know if this is still so.

Comment: True. A step up from *not* viewing the source, though :)

Comment: I did not know that I had to check the source or use text/plain. Thank to all.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this. I didn't know what was going on either and this helped me a bunch! :)